# How to get the Solution Path in C# and not the path of debug folder?

Tags: c#, directory

I want to reference a folder, which is located next to the .csproj File. For this i want to get the path of the solution File or the .csproj File.

The Problem i have is, that i am only able to get a path like that "bin\debug\net6" but my folder is in the same folder, where the bin folder is in. Does anyone have an idea how to get that?

I know that i could navigate through the folders up to my project File Folder but i would like to look for a better solution

So far i tried:
`Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`
`AppContext.BaseDirectory`
`Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location`
`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`

All of that pointed to the bin\debug\net6 folder.

Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("$(SolutionDir)") was null

Comment: During runtime? Why is that?

Comment: Because there is a config file i want to update when i start my project. And the config file is in a subfolder of the project File directory. So in a release version this should be no problem but during developing and debuging this crashes the client which is connected to my project

Comment: Copy the config file into the output path of your project would be the typical thing to do. If the file is part of the project then simply set its "Copy to Output Directory" property appropriately.

Comment: At runtime, there is no concept of a "solution" anyway so you can't get that. As Ralf says, copy the file somewhere known and use that instead.